# How to make my converter go in descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a conversion table which converts miles to kilometres and kilometres to miles depending on whichever one the user chooses. They input two numbers which indicates the two ranges so if they input `2` and `5` and choose `km` to `m` it will then show `2km` to `5km` converted to miles. However, what I am trying to do is if the user inputs a greater number to start with for instance if you enter `10` and `2` it should still do the same but rather it should go from `10km` down to `2km` so in descending order, so I know it will be something along the lines of `if(rangeStart>rangeEnd){i--;}`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
function conversion(n) {
if (document.getElementById('mtokm').checked) {
    return (n/0.62137).toFixed(2);
}
else {
return (n*0.62137).toFixed(2);
}
    }

function conversionTable(rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
if(atLeastOneRadio() && rangeStart != false && rangeEnd != false) {

divStr="<table border=1><tr><td>Miles</td><td>Kilometres</td></tr>";}


    for(i=rangeStart;i<=rangeEnd;i++) {
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        divStr+= "<tr bgcolor=\"yellow\"><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + conversion(i) + "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        divStr+= "<tr bgcolor=\"green\"><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + conversion(i) + "</td></tr>";
    }
  }
    document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML=divStr;
 }
  else
  {
alert("Please make sure you have entered an integer in both text boxes");
  }
}

function getnputValue(input) {
var nn = $("input[name=convert]:checked").val()
var myInt = document.getElementById(input).value;
if(myInt == parseInt(myInt))
return parseInt(myInt);
else
    return false;

}




function check() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("choice");
    $("input[name=convert]:checked").val()
    for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        return true;
}
}

return false;
}

function atLeastOneRadio() {
    return ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Start : <input type=textbox id=rangeTxt value=""/>
    End : <input type=textbox id=rangeTxt2 value=""/>
    <input type=radio name="convert" id="mtokm" value ="Miles to Kilometre"/>        Miles to Kilometre
    <input type=radio name="convert" id="kmtom" value ="Kilometre to Miles"/>  Kilometre to Miles
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onClick="conversionTable(getnputValue('rangeTxt'),        getnputValue('rangeTxt2'))">Convert</button>
    </p>
    <div id="divResult">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the end is higher or lower than the start. Then set variables that are used to control the `for` loop.

```
var increment, compare;
if (rangeStart <= rangeEnd) {
    increment = 1;
    compare = function(x, y) {
        return x <= y;
    };
} else {
    increment = -1;
    compare = function(x, y) {
        return x >= y;
    };
}

for (i = rangeStart; compare(i, rangeEnd); i += increment) {
    // display code
}
```